# Docker pull error: failed to register layer: ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout: stderr: lchown ...: invalid argument

Tags: docker, docker-compose, virtual-machine

There is a docker image I built which I suddenly can't pull into my Debian VM anymore. It works on every other machine but on my VM I get the error:

```
failed to register layer: ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout:  stderr: lchown /app/node_modules/buffer-equal-constant-time/.npmignore: invalid argument
```

My docker version is `20.10.12` but it also fails with the latest version `20.10.22`.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same issue trying to pull `Shinobi` docker image on unprivileged Proxmox container.

Problem is located inside obsolete `buffer-equal-constant-time` node module. More about issue you can found here: [docker pull error: stdout: stderr: lchown ... invalid argument](https://gitlab.com/Shinobi-Systems/Shinobi/-/issues/452)

**Fast workaround:** build Shinobi docker image from source on machine where problem occurs.